# Quickblox Uploading of Files

Tags: ios, iphone, upload, quickblox

I have an issue with uploading files via QuickBlox service, it appeared recently, I don't know when exactly, but I noticed today.

Now, when I call the method:

`[QBRequest completeBlobWithID:blob.ID size:fileSize successBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
}
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
}`

I always get the error.

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "Expected status code in (200-299), got 422";
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "{\"errors\":{\"blob\":[\"is not uploaded yet\"]}}";
```

[image]

I didn't any changes in code. But for now I have this problem.
You can test this issue [here](https://github.com/maximbilan/iOS-QuickBlox-File-Uploader-Downloader).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we updated the AWS SDK on the backend and now all parameters a bit different

Actually I recommend to use

```
                NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"London" ofType:@"jpg"]];

                [QBRequest TUploadFile:file fileName:@"Great Image" contentType:@"image/jpg" isPublic:NO successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBCBlob *blob) {
                    NSLog(@"Successfull response!");
                } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {
                    NSLog(@"upload progress: %f", status.percentOfCompletion);
                } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                    NSLog(@"Response error: %@", response.error);
                }];
```

It does all 3 requests, so you don't need to parse all these parameters manually

Anyway, if you still want to run these 3 requests manually then just replace old parameters with new.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use this method, because we have a big size content, and we need load data from file, not from memory.

Comment: I think I should follow the next documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html#sigv4-post-example-file-upload? Is it right?